# Was the third riddle from "Little Dot" supposed to reference another story?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, diana-wynne-jones

Recently I was rereading Diana Wynne-Jones's short story, "Little Dot", and as I was reading, I began wondering about the third riddle - I thought I had read something similar elsewhere.

The riddle is "What kills as a lion, and as human wins", and the answer is

> "The Beast of Ettmoor" - the one asking the riddle, who has a human guise, but kills as the beast.

The story does contain some deliberate references to other riddle stories, from Turandot, to the Sphinx and her riddle, to the first riddle being a well known nonsense riddle.  So it occurred to be that nagging familiarity might be because I should know the other story, but can't recall it.  Perhaps it is well known enough I'll feel silly for having forgotten, perhaps there isn't one and it's just this story getting mixed with other beast-riddle stories in my memory.

So my question is, is there another riddle-beast story, where the answer to the riddle is the beast asking? Bonus if the story is well known, or if the beast is a shape-shifter, but it could still work if not.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is a reference to a specific similar riddle in an earlier work.  However, it does appear to be an example of a common trope in stories about riddle contests:  having a final riddle that is unfair, because it asks for something that no one other than the questioner could possibly know.  The best known example of this in contemporary fantasy fiction is Bilbo Bagggins asking:  "What have I got in my pocket?"

However, these kinds of unfair final questions are much older.  Both the *Elder Edda* and the *Saga of King Heidrek the Wise* involve riddle contests where one of the contestants is the god Odin in disguise.  In each case, after trading fair riddles, Odin stumped his opponent by asking:  *What did Odin whisper in the ear of his son Baldur, before he was carried to his funeral pyre?*  Like the riddle from "Little Dot," the answer could only be known to the questioner, who was in disguise.

Another riddle contest (from an entirely different strand of western cultural tradition) is the riddle of Samson.  There is only one riddle, but it is unfair in the same way.  Samson asks his Philistine guests:  *Out of the eater, something to eat; out of the strong, something sweet.*  This was a reference to recent events, in which Samson had killed a lion and then found bees and honey inside its corpse.  This riddle in "Little Dot" may also have been intended as a partial allusion to this unfair riddle, since both involve lions, albeit in very different ways.